FATAL ERROR: v8::HandleScope::CreateHandle() Cannot create a handle without a HandleScope
I am using Faiss Node and while using FaissStore.load I am getting the following error for the 2nd time:
FATAL ERROR: v8::HandleScope::CreateHandle() Cannot create a handle without a HandleScope
----- Native stack trace -----

 1: 0x10acc1ef4 node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 2: 0x10ae98761 v8::Utils::ReportApiFailure(char const*, char const*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 3: 0x10b0250b2 v8::internal::HandleScope::Extend(v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 4: 0x10ae994ad v8::EscapableHandleScope::EscapableHandleScope(v8::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 5: 0x10ac76d3d napi_open_escapable_handle_scope [/usr/local/bin/node]
 6: 0x671cba9c1 Napi::FunctionReference::New(std::initializer_list<napi_value__*> const&) const [/Users/Desktop/Projects/node_modules/faiss-node/build/Release/faiss-node.node]
 7: 0x671cbe571 IndexBase<IndexFlatL2, faiss::IndexFlatL2>::read(Napi::CallbackInfo const&) [/Users/Desktop/Projects/node_modules/faiss-node/build/Release/faiss-node.node]
 8: 0x671cbfb6f napi_value__* Napi::details::WrapCallback<Napi::ObjectWrap<IndexFlatL2>::StaticMethodCallbackWrapper(napi_env__*, napi_callback_info__*)::'lambda'()>(Napi::ObjectWrap<IndexFlatL2>::StaticMethodCallbackWrapper(napi_env__*, napi_callback_info__*)::'lambda'()) [/Users/Desktop/Projects/node_modules/faiss-node/build/Release/faiss-node.node]
 9: 0x671cbf88d Napi::ObjectWrap<IndexFlatL2>::StaticMethodCallbackWrapper(napi_env__*, napi_callback_info__*) [/Users/Desktop/Projects/node_modules/faiss-node/build/Release/faiss-node.node]
10: 0x10ac79620 v8impl::(anonymous namespace)::FunctionCallbackWrapper::Invoke(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&) [/usr/local/bin/node]
11: 0x10b86a1dd Builtins_CallApiCallbackGeneric [/usr/local/bin/node]

I am trying to use FaissStore.load function from https://www.npmjs.com/package/faiss-node
